# Installing a lower IOS version than the latest one to a device

Tags: iphone, ios, installation, itunes, jailbreak

I know that it is possible to install lower versions of IOS to jailbroken devices over various tools by creating custom firmware.The problem is we have some test devices in the company and we want to have one device eactly with IOS 4.3. It will not be downgrade since the device itself has IOs 4.2.1 installed.Is there a documented way to active it and the most importantly where can i find older IOS versions?

Comment: http://www.iphonefirmware.com/firmwares-download/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't want you to install anything but the latest version available of iOS, so every install of a firmware will get checked with Apple's servers.

There is a way to save the authorization for other firmwares with tools like TinyUmbrella, but you can only save the authorization of the currently allowed version; so, if you did not use TinyUmbrella 2 years ago when iOS 4 was the newest version, there is no way to downgrade your device.

Comment: He doesn't want to downgrade, he has 4.2.1 and wants to install 4.3

Comment: shall i maybe just jailbrak the device and install custom firmware =)

Comment: i tired like 3 ipsw files and 3 ituens versions but still got the same

Comment: you can always install the latest available version for your device. if you jailbreak you might be able to install other version's, too.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT:
Editing because this no longer works and it gets downvoted by people who didn't read the comments.

Apple wants us to use the latest version, and develop for the latest version, there is no way of downgrading **anymore**.

OLD ANSWER:
You can download any firmware for any iOS device here

[iOS Downloads](http://www.getios.com/)

To install it, you have to go to iTunes and click on update with the **alt** key pressed, then you can choose the `.ipsw` file with the firmware you want.

For the  "This device isn't elegible..." message try [this](http://leimobile.com/this-device-isnt-eligible-for-the-requested-build/)

Comment: it shows me the following error "This device isnot eligable for teh requested build" ?

Comment: it is recommended to comment out the line 74.208.10.249 gs.apple.com in /etc/hosts file but i do not have that line in hosts at all

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the correct ipsw file for your device?

Comment: yes sure iPod4,1_4.3_8F190_Restore is ifle name and i have i pod 4th generation with 4.2.1 installed

Comment: could it be something related with my baseband?

Comment: I don't think so, try with an older iTunes version.

Comment: i also tried with 10.5 it did not help either

Comment: Is the device with jailbreak?

Comment: take a look to my last edit, I added a link that can solve your problem

Comment: This link only helps when you saved your shsh when the old version was the current one

Comment: He doesn't want to downgrade. Try this: check /private/etc/hosts and /etc/host, if any of this is pressent (74.208.105.171 gs.apple.com and/or 74.208.10.249 gs.apple.com) delete them, and then add 17.112.176.11 gs.apple.com, save to desktop and replace the old one with this one

Comment: it doesn't matter if you want to downgrade or upgrade.. apple only authorizes the latest released version for the device

Comment: I agree with @Bastian's comment, but surely there has to be a way? If you are developing to support iOS 7.x devices, you need to be able to test against a real 7.x device, so downgrading to an earlier release should be allowed somehow. Shouldn't it?

Comment: No, apple wants us to use the latest version, and develop for the latest version, there is no way of downgrading anymore. I have some devices and keep some of them without updating so I can test.